# How to change default size of 25mb of notebook in anaconda

Tags: python, smtp

So here is the deal, I have a 268mb notebook in python, and I am not able to run it because notebooks have a default size of 25mb, so I need a basic guide on how to change it, I'm kind new in programming, so I really need help.

```
import smtplib, ssl
import mimetypes
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import formataddr
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import pandas as pd
import os
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr




#colocando o nome das pessoas na watermark
dados = pd.read_excel('Lista investimentos.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet4')
#colocando o nome dos arquivos
dados1 = pd.read_excel('Lista investimentos.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet3')
###Creating a list in excel
emails = dados.values.tolist()
nome = dados1.values.tolist()#colocando o nome das pessoas na watermark


j=0
for i in range(len(emails)):
    message = EmailMessage()
    sender = formataddr((str(Header('Sender Name', 'utf-8')), 'email@gmail.com'))
    recipient = emails[i][0]
    message['From'] = sender
    message['To'] = recipient
    message['Subject'] = 'Subject'
    body = """Body."""
    message.set_content(body)
    APOSTILA = nome[i][0]
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(APOSTILA)
    mime_type, mime_subtype = mime_type.split('/')
    with open(APOSTILA, 'rb') as file:
         message.add_attachment(file.read(),
         maintype=mime_type,
         subtype=mime_subtype,
         filename=APOSTILA)
    print(message)
    mail_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
    mail_server.set_debuglevel(1)
    mail_server.login("email@gmail.com", 'password')
    mail_server.send_message(message)
    mail_server.quit()
    j=j+1
print(i)
```

every "apostila" has a size of 4.6mb, and the len(email) = 120

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do and exactly why it isn't working

Comment: I reformed the question

Comment: Since it creates a heavy notebook of 256 mb, and default size of notebook's in anaconda is 25mb, after running it, I can't open